# Use mask to count hourly slots from multiple datetime columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to calculate the load(or strain?) in a waiting room.
I have the timedate's for `arrival`, `start of treatment` and `finish`(randomly generated below).

I would like to calculate the load in some defined interval (f.ex. per hour).

In pseudo code

```
for each hour in total time:
    load = (arrival[hour] + (arrival[<hour] && finish[=>hour])).count()
```

`load` is more or less: how many arrived during the slot + how many where still there from previous slots.

The timings are for many months and I would like to get an overview, by aggregating data into one week, hourly slots; I think it's a `MultiIndex` of `{day, hour}` as for `df2` below. This is my MWE.

```
from datetime import timedelta
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# generate random arrival/waiting and finish dates.
startday= pd.to_datetime("1/1/2021")
endday = pd.to_datetime("1/14/2021")

# 10**9 is to convert between ns and s
arrival= pd.DatetimeIndex(
        (10**9*np.random.randint(startday.value//10**9, endday.value//10**9, 2000))
    ).sort_values()
treatment = pd.DatetimeIndex(
    [s + timedelta(minutes=np.random.randint(5, 55)) for s in arrival]
)
finish = pd.DatetimeIndex(
    [s + timedelta(minutes=np.random.randint(15, 60)) for s in treatment]
)

# each row shows when a person arrived, how long she waited and when she left
waiting = treatment - arrival
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "arrival": arrival,
        "treatment": treatment,
        "finish": finish,
        "waiting": waiting,
    },
    index=arrival,
)

# group into hourly bins over one week
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "arrival": df["arrival"]
        .groupby([(idx := df["arrival"].dt).weekday, idx.hour])
        .count(),
        "treatment": df["treatment"]
        .groupby([(idx := df["treatment"].dt).weekday, idx.hour])
        .count(),
        "finish": df["finish"]
        .groupby([(idx := df["finish"].dt).weekday, idx.hour])
        .count(),
    },
).fillna(0)
# fillna fails if waiting is added
df2["waiting"] = (
    df["waiting"].groupby([(idx := df["arrival"].dt).weekday, idx.hour]).mean()
)
```

Help calculating `load` would be much appreciated. I spent many hours in vain.

Simple example

```
arrival = [10.00, 10.15, 10,45, 11.30, 11.45, 12.15]
finish =  [10.30, 10.59, 11.45, 12.30, 12.45, 13.00]
```

Then `load = arrival + 'people still not finished'`

```
load = {"10": 3+0, "11": 2+1, "12":1+2}
```

That have to work for all days.

Best regards,

Comment: have you looked at ```cumcount()```

Comment: you essentially have queues, which are step functions, defined by start and stop times, eg the waiting queue is defined by `arrival` and `treatment`. You may want to look at a package, built on pandas, called [staircase](https://www.staircase.dev) which handles step functions. You can slice step functions by arbitrary time points and calculate the mean queue size of each slice. [See this example on queues](https://www.staircase.dev/en/latest/case_studies/queues.html)

Comment: I looked `cumcount()` up, but I cannot see how I can use it here. I'm stuck because I don't know how to compare the dates. I think that have to be done before grouping,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['arrival_date_hour'] = df.arrival.apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%y-%m-%d %H'))
df['finish_date_hour'] = df.finish.apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%y-%m-%d %H'))

result_df = pd.DataFrame({'arrival_date_hour':df.arrival_date_hour.unique(), 'load':None}).set_index('arrival_date_hour')

for datehour in df.arrival_date_hour.unique():
    load = df[(df.finish_date_hour >= datehour) & (df.arrival_date_hour <= datehour)].shape[0]
    result_df.loc[datehour] = load
```

Result would look something like:

```
arrival_date_hour   load
21-01-01 00         10
21-01-01 01         18
21-01-01 02         19
21-01-01 03         19
21-01-01 04         21
...                 ...
21-01-13 19         19
21-01-13 20         20
21-01-13 21         17
21-01-13 22         21
21-01-13 23         20
```

###### UPDATE

Try this to get a mean of your load based on weekday and hour:

```
result_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
result_df['arrival_date_hour'] = result_df.arrival_date_hour.apply(
    datetime.strptime,
    args=["%y-%m-%d %H"])
result_df['hour'] = result_df.arrival_date_hour.apply(lambda x: x.hour)
result_df['weekday'] = result_df.arrival_date_hour.apply(datetime.weekday)
result_df.groupby(['weekday', 'hour']).load.mean()
```

Comment: @Paw does this help?

Comment: Yep, this is perfect. Thank you very much.

Another question: What is the idiomatic way to convert the index of `result_df` to `datetime64` and then group the load with a `Multiindex` of `{weekdaynumber, hour}` so load is `averaged`(or aggregated?) into 168 averages?

Like I tried to do with the data in `df2`.

Comment: Added an update, you can switch around with hour/weekday or with the type of aggregation if needed.